# Cast function pointer to return const ref instead of plain ref

Tags: c++

I have a function pointer, of type `T`, and need to return a `ConstT` as shown:

```
using T = int&(*)(void*);
using ConstT = const int&(*)(void*);

ConstT get_const_pointer(T func_ptr) {
    return static_cast<ConstT>(func_ptr);
}
```

Using clang I get the compilation error:

```
static_cast from 'int&(*)(void*)' to 'const int&(*)(void*)' not allowed
```

I get a similar error when using `const_cast`. Is this possible/safe to do?

EDIT:
I have realized that I could define the above function as follows:

```
ConstT get_const_ptr(T func_ptr) {
    return +[func_ptr](void* ptr) { return func_ptr(ptr); };
}
```

This requires creating an extra function somewhere in memory though, which (according to my understanding of const and runtitme behaviour) doesn't seem like it should be necessary, as this function ptr should do /exactly/ the same thing as the original function ptr, but it adds the type information in `const`. Why should a reinterpret_cast be required to do this without a new function definition?

Comment: try reinterpret_cast

Comment: What type do you intent `ConstT` to be? You can't call a function through a function pointer to a different function type. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user1095108 And then have UB when using the result? There is a reason the compiler forbids you from doing this with a `static_cast`.

Comment: I intend for the function pointer to return a constant reference to the same int in memory. I am worried about safety around using the reinterpret_cast, although it does *seem* to work. What is the reason that `static_cast` is forbidden?

Comment: @alexelias "_To the same int in memory_": What `int`? There is no `int` object in the code you have shown. What you are trying to do seems completely pointless anyway. If you have a non-`const` reference already, why do you need a `const` one? Casting the result of the function call would be well-defined but probably useless, but calling the result of the `reinterpret_cast`ed function pointer is UB. What is the specific use case you have for this?

Comment: @alexelias Because using the result of the cast would automatically be undefined behavior. `reinterpret_cast` doesn't care about that. It allows casting almost everything to everything else, no matter whether the result can be reasonably used without UB.

Comment: Your edit will not compile. Where do you think you need this `get_const_ptr` function's result instead of just calling `func_ptr` or an overload directly? I can't think of any use case for that.

Comment: I am using function pointers as a type-erased way of defining getters so that you can keep the ability to access relevant parts of a struct with only this 'getter' (function pointer) and a pointer to the start of the struct instance.

Comment: @alexelias I don't see how this is needed for that use case.

Comment: Just to be clear about the question as such: `get_const_ptr` is impossible to implement without the resulting pointer causing undefined behavior when called. You need to define new functions for each function pointer value or a function template taking the pointer as template argument to get something roughly similar. You should probably ask about your actual use case instead. There is probably a different approach to that.

Comment: lol, try returning a void pointer then, or std::variant or std::any.

Comment: Re: "I intend for the function pointer to return a constant reference ..."` -- function pointers don't return anything. They are data, not code. Don't muddle the **pointer** with the **thing it points at**.